# How to change the default colour of metropolis beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, color, beamer-metropolis

I want to change the default color of the metropolis theme to the one shown in the image below. I am unable to find the command to change the color of the frametitle and the block environment. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please always include a short, but compilable test document in your questions!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `palette primary` colour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\definecolor{mPurple}{RGB}{91,48,105}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=mPurple}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
  abc
  \begin{block}{title}
  content...
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the text color to be black.

Comment: @RajeshDey See my updated answer